# Do relational databases typically understand '1' and '0' as booleans?

Tags: relational-theory, datatypes

I'm working on a code library that helps users build database searches from form inputs (a layer on top of an ORM). I want it to be compatible with most relational databases.

I currently have a method for checkbox inputs that converts `'1'` into `true` and `'0'` into `false`, but I wonder if it's necessary.

From my testing, PostgreSQL and MySQL already understand these values as booleans.

```
database  |SELECT true = '1'|SELECT true = '0'|SELECT false = '1'|SELECT false = '0'|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL|      t          |         f       |        f         |        t         |
MySQL     |      1          |         0       |        0         |        1         |
```

Is this true of other major relational databases - eg, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, and DB2? Is it a SQL standard?

Comment: I don't think it's in the standard. And some DBMS (SQL Server for example) do not have boolean type. In MySQL `boolean` means `tinyint` so it's not a real boolean type. It just seems to behave like one. Try `SELECT (true=17) ;` for example.

Comment: How about using bit?

Comment: `boolean` is a ANSI SQL datatype and I'm actually surprised that `false = '1'` doesn't throw an error in Postgres because it's comparing a boolean with a string. The standard only defines `true` and `false` as valid boolean literals.

Comment: @ypercube: MySQL's "broken" boolean handling becomes even more obvious with expressions like `where 'foo'` (evaluates to `false`) and `where '1foo'` (which evaluates to `true`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually three (boolean literals): `true`, `false` and `unknown` ;)

Comment: No Booleans in Oracle SQL, although PL/SQL supports it.